# Writing Python script for plugin to filter out high slope areas in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am currently developing a Python plugin using the Python QGIS API that tries to automate basic constraint analysis. So far, I am able to add buffers to parcel, wetland, and floodzone areas. But, I would now also like to write some code that will identify high slope areas on a DEM layer. Doing this will allow me to further restrain my build area.

So far, I am able to save the DEM layer to a raster object like so -

```
rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('38_77_3688')[0]
```

I have taken a look at the Python QGIS API documentation and have come across the interesting class `class qgis.analysis.QgsSlopeFilter` at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/analysis/QgsSlopeFilter.html. But I am having some trouble understanding how to use this class.

Can someone explain what `QgsSlopeFilter` does or point me to a more useful class that will allow me to filter out the high slope areas in the DEM layer?

Comment: did you figure this out? I am wanting to iterate through a series of DEMs and extract areas with 20% or greater slope.